# How to generate an on-behalf-of token for a middle-tier API

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to implement an [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow, with Microsoft Identity Platform where my Web app authenticates users, then makes a request to my Web API which in turn makes a request to the Microsoft Graph API (and returns the result to the Web app).

> My problem is that I will need to pass on an on-behalf-of token to my Web API for it to be granted acces to Microsoft Graph, but I cannot manage to generate this token. (I'm trying to generate this token using Postman at the moment.)

What I want to be able to run is a code snippet provided by the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#on-behalf-of-provider) for the Microsoft Graph SDK (in the case of an OBO-flow), and what I need help with is how to generate the token for the `oboToken` variable.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "Presence.Read.All" };

var tenantId = "common";

var clientId = "<id of my API as registered in Azure AD / App Registrations>";
var clientSecret = "<value from Client Secret in Registerd Application / Certificates & secrets";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var oboToken = "< WHAT NEEDS TO BE PROVIDED BY THE WEB APP >";

var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
    var assertion = new UserAssertion(oboToken);
    var result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

    request.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

Console.WriteLine(graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result);
```

---

I've tried the following: I generate an authorization code with the following request in my browser

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=< Id of my API >
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
```

Then, with the returned code, make the following POST request (from Postman)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?
client_id=< Id of my API >
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code=< code returned by request above >
```

When I use the returned token from the response as the value of the `oboToken` in the code snippet, I get a

> MsalServiceException: AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed.

If I instead also include a `client_secret` parameter in the POST request above for a token, I get the response *AADSTS90023: Public clients can't send a client secret*.

> How could I generate an on-behalf-of token to be able to run the provided code snippet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your mistake is getting an MS Graph API token with the authorization code flow.

The way it should work is:

1. Web App gets an access token to the Web API using authorization code flow
2. Web API receives the access token and exchanges it for an MS Graph API token using the on-behalf-of flow
3. Web API calls MS Graph API

So when your Web App gets an access token, it should use a scope defined in the API app registration instead of `scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default`.
If you specify an MS Graph API scope, you get an access token for MS Graph API, meaning you are trying to call MS Graph API from the Web App, instead of your API.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the scope to a scope defined for my API- both in the authorization code request and the access token request - seems to produce a valid access token wich I can use as the `oboToken` above. But now I'v got an "AuthenticationError" error instead.  I need access to the scope *Presence.Read.All* when calling the Graph API, do I need to specify this somehow when I produce the access token to be exchanged?

Comment: Ah, you've run into one of the issues when using the OBO flow I think. When you sign in to the Web App, you are only granting consent for that app, not the API. But you can do that: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#gaining-consent-for-the-middle-tier-application. Basically you have two choices here: 1) Add the Web App client ID to the knownClientApplications property to the API app registration manifest. This will cause the consent form to ask consent to the API as well. 2) Grant admin consent to the API app through AAD portal.

Comment: For option 1, you may have to force consent with `prompt=consent`. Oh, and you need to use the special ".default" scope, e.g. "your-api-client-id/.default".

Comment: Thanks, but I still cannot get the `DelegatedApplicationProvider` to work. I've aded the Id of the WebApp to the "knownClientApplications" array and I refer to the .default scope of my API, when I request an authorization code, and an acces token to my API.

Comment: I've also made sure to have delegated permissions to Microsoft Graph (User.Read.All and Presence.Read.All) in my API (the API as a registered application in Azure Ad).

Comment: Did you get a consent window during login?

Comment: Yes I do get a consent window.

Comment: If you check the API app in the "Enterprise applications" section, does it show the required permission under Permissions tab?

Comment: Yes, they all show up (as Granted trough Admin consent).

Comment: What error do you get when getting the MS Graph API token?

Comment: I get 'Code: AuthenticationError
Message: Error authenticating with resource
Inner error:'

Comment: I've tried to request for the scopes "User.Read.All" and "Presence.Read.All", or for https://graph.microsoft.com/.default .

Comment: I am using the same flow and getting the same issue any success or solution?